# How to get a HTML page in nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body> This is the body</body>
</html>
```

How do I modify this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

to return **test.html** above?

Comment: Did you try searching first? Found http://thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/5/6/serving-static-files-from-node-js pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a simple streaming static server

```
var basepath = '/files'

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    res.writeHead(400);
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  var s = fs.createReadStream(path.join(basepath, req.path));
  s.on('error', function () {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end();
  });
  s.once('fd', function () {
    res.writeHead(200);
  });
  s.pipe(res);
});
```

In practice you should use express.static: http://runnable.com/UWw3g0PKxoAWAA6K

Or a deticated static module like https://github.com/jesusabdullah/node-ecstatic